# Doubts and issues about female discharge

Tags: jannah, ghusl

getting this colourless, clear, transparent discharge I thought it was regular vaginal discharge but I’m really doubting myself now and I’m unsure if I have to do ghusl I don’t know what to do, because I get this discharge when I’m getting on with my life and I also get this discharge if I have dirty thoughts it never really comes out I wipe and it’s there. Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: ghusl is necessary in case of menses (or what is similar to that like child bed bleeding) or wet dreams or after intercourse and your statement doesn't seem to refer to any of those.

Comment: I mean at times I get dirty thoughts and get this clear, colourless transparent discharge, but I also get this discharge randomly when I’m just getting on with my day so I’m unsure whether ghusl janabah becomes necessary?!

Comment: Janabah is related to intercourse that either includes penetration or(and) ejaculation. Or a wet dream your description rather seem to refer to neither of both, as dirty thoughts are rather related to awakness. Am I understanding you correctly? If so then we could exclude the necessity for ghusl.